# How to center a LinearLayout in RealativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to center a LinearLayout (inside a RelativeLayout) and for whatever reason - it just won't center. It keeps sticking to the left. Help much appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/main_background"
   tools:context=".SlideActivity"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true">

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/slideViewPager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/dotsLayout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/slideViewPager"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:padding="20dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MjhGpGhqBM_SJa1j3soEL31ZzoAkf6pg/view?usp=sharing
The 3 dots on the bottom should be *centered*. HOWEVER they stick to the left...

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this line:

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

so your layout won't stick (align) to the start of the parent (to the left in your case), and because you already have:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

You `LinearLayout` will be in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "layout_alignParentStart = true" - this seems to be in conflict with "layout_centerInParent = true".

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all kind of alignment attribute and only keep this :

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    tools:context=".SlideActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/slideViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/slideViewPager"
        android:id="@+id/dotsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```